# fopen file in appdata folder (wamp)

Tags: php, apache, wamp, wampserver, php-5.6

I have some csv file in this path:

```
C:\Users\myusername\AppData\Roaming\some_file.csv
```

I want to open this file by **`fopen()`** from my www dir (wamp).
Here my try:

```
$my_file = fopen('C:\Users\myusername\AppData\Roaming\some_file.csv', 'r');
```

Here what I get:

> ```
> "failed to open stream: No such file or directory"
> ```

Thanks.

Comment: Your wamp server is probably running under different account, so it has not access to files of user `myusername`

Comment: My wamp is running in the same user (I have only 1 user in my computer)

Answer (score 1):

Well I just tested this code as you show it and it works just fine.

I would in future use unix forward slashes rather than dos backslashes, but without any changes your code worked on my WAMPServer 2.5 with Apache2.4.9 and PHP5.6.12

So that just leaves the question, have you used the correct filename in your code?

***Just for future reference***:

You do not only have one account on your system! WAMPServer runs as `Local System Account`, unless you have done something to change that. Have you? Because if you have, that could be at least part of your problem!

Answer (score 0):

The `\` character has a special meaning in many languages, PHP included, so that string with the file path may not hold the value you think it does. What should work is something like:

`$my_file = fopen('C:\\Users\\myusername\\AppData\\Roaming\\some_file.csv', 'r');`

This tells the interpreter that you want the actual `\` character in the string and that you're not trying to use an escape sequence. You can more about how they work in PHP [here](http://www.hackingwithphp.com/2/6/2/escape-sequences). You can also use single forward slashes instead, which should work fine on Windows.

Comment: Hmm, you can maybe try doing a simple `echo file_exists("C:\\Users\\myusername\\AppData\\Roaming\\some_file.csv");` just to make sure that the path is correct. If the path is right, it should print a 1.

Comment: something interesting -
I moved the file to AppData folder and now the file os opened well, how I can access the file when is in Roaming folder?